# Commerce product options on product basis

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce and I would like to create product attributes. So customer can adjust some attributes before he would buy an item.

I know, that there are some commerce modules, that enable attributes / options of product. But I cannot find such module, that would enable setting attribute options separately for each product.

I have found [Pricing Attributes module](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes), but I can set options only globally, not separately for each product. I can set separately only price and enable/disable options. But I am not able to add new options.

Is it possible to add new attributes options to product using  UI with some commerce module?
If not, can anybody help to find documentation or API, how could I set product options programatically by myself without existing attribute modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal Commerce generally conceives of attributes as those things about a product that a customer might specify on the Add to Cart form to drill down to a particular SKU, i.e. a particular variation in a group of products. From this perspective, you wouldn't have the ability to randomly add options to a product for selection on the Add to Cart form; you'd define attributes as fields on your product type and create a unique product for each potential variation.

You can use line item fields and expose them to the Add to Cart form, allowing the customer to enrich the line item with additional information required for fulfilling the product that do not affect the SKU. There are videos showing both of these different features in our video library:

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/videos

Finally, I met Joshua Needham at BADCamp, and I believe he intends to put some time into the Commerce Product Options module. This was a suite of modules initially developed by hunziker and then left on its own for a year or two. If Joshua is able to get commit access, I'd expect to see some work in there that allowed for product by product configurable bundles of options that are exposed through the line item form. I'd pull up a link for that but drupal.org is down atm. : )

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [commerce Kickstart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) module which includes drupal core itself.It has attributes settings in it for each product.
You should try that on [simplytestme](http://simplytest.me/) site